# how to assign certificate for ActiveMQ ssl transport Connector?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have enabled ssl transport Connector in Active MQ Version 5.17.1 (in activemq.xml) using this line:

`<transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:29617?transport.needClientAuth=true&amp;maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=209715200&amp;jms.prefetchPolicy.all=10"/>`

which is structured like this:

```xml
<beans>
  <broker>
    <transportConnectors>
      <transportConnector ....../>
    </transportConnector>
  </broker>
</beans>
```

How do I tell this connector now which broker.ks and broker.ts (and the corresponding passwords) to use? I could not find anything on the web except the java options as in
https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl
but those "effect all SSL users in a JVM". Is there a way to define .ks and .ts per connector? and where would I put it in the xml structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add configuration to the ActiveMQ XML configuration file to provide the location and credentials for the key store so you don't need to use the environment variable option.

```
     <sslContext>
        <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks"
          keyStorePassword="password" trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ts"
          trustStorePassword="password"/>
    </sslContext>
```

The broker distribution ships with example configurations that demonstrate a configured broker with SSL enabled.